# resample twice in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a serios of data talked about the daily rainfall.I want to calculate 3-day rainfall sum, and use this 3-day rainfall sum to obtain maximum 3-day rainfall for each calendar month.After that, I want to use maximum 3-day rainfall for each calendar month to select every November data.

Firstly, I use the resample function to get the 3-days data.

```
df_rain_3d = df_rain_1d.resample(rule = '3D', on='date', label='right').sum()
```

Second, when I want to resample by each month, it doesn't work.

```
df_rain_3d_m = df_rain_3d.resample(rule = '1M', on='date').max().to_period('m')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the meaning of the last part:  "*After that, I want to use maximum 3-day rainfall for each calendar month to select every November data.*"?

Comment: Welcome. Please look at it form our perspective: How are we supposed to guess what is your issue if we have neither a sample of your data, nor in what manner "it doesnt work", in a a nutshell, a [mre]? Some essential reading to help us help you: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12846804)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following Minimal Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
N = 365 * 4 + 1
df_rain_1d = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020', periods=N, freq='D'),
                           'rain': rng.integers(0, 20, N)})
print(df_rain_1d)

# Output
           date  rain
0    2020-01-01     1
1    2020-01-02    15
2    2020-01-03    13
3    2020-01-04     8
4    2020-01-05     8
...         ...   ...
1456 2023-12-27    19
1457 2023-12-28     9
1458 2023-12-29     5
1459 2023-12-30    10
1460 2023-12-31    15

[1461 rows x 2 columns]
```

The first part seems to work:

```
df_rain_3d = df_rain_1d.resample(rule='3D', on='date', label='right').sum()
print(df_rain_3d)

# Output
            rain
date            
2020-01-04    29
2020-01-07    33
2020-01-10    18
2020-01-13    30
2020-01-16    43
...          ...
2023-12-20    51
2023-12-23     7
2023-12-26    16
2023-12-29    29
2024-01-01    30

[487 rows x 1 columns]
```

Now the second part does not work. You should notice that the date is no longer a column but your index so the `on` parameter of the `resample` method should not be used:

```
df_rain_3d_m = df_rain_3d.resample(rule='1M').max().to_period('m')
print(df_rain_3d_m)

# Output
         rain
date         
2020-01    43
2020-02    44
2020-03    42
2020-04    43
2020-05    37
...
2023-09    39
2023-10    55
2023-11    47
2023-12    51
2024-01    30
```

Finally, I suppose you want to extract November from each year:

```
df_rain_3d_m_nov = df_rain_3d_m.loc[df_rain_3d_m.index.month == 11]
print(df_rain_3d_m_nov)

# Output
         rain
date         
2020-11    41
2021-11    52
2022-11    39
2023-11    47
```